# Plotting functions witz Tikz - where does this hole come from?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot a Hyperbola but for some reason it puts a hole in the plot and I can't figure out what causes it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=(1/sqrt(2)):2,smooth,thick,samples=100] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)});
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=-2:(-1/sqrt(2)),smooth,thick,samples=100] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)});

\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=(1/sqrt(2)):2,smooth,thick,samples=100] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)});
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=-2:(-1/sqrt(2)),smooth,thick,samples=100] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try increasing "samples=100" to e.g. "samples=1000" From experience, I believe it's about approximation of functions with piece-wise linear parts.

Comment: Alternatively use `pgfplots` to plot instead. It handles this much better. Plus has automatic axises etc.

Comment: @daleif I was considering that already. Do you mind posting a solution using this package? I haven't used it before. Maybe I can learn for my other graphics by looking at your example.

Comment: @EricScöerg The hole is still there for me.

Comment: You might also consider using a parametric plot with x=sec(t)/sqrt(2) and y=tan(t), but this requires gnuplot (shell escape).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question why there is a gap is

> because LaTeX is not a computer algebra system.

So we have to help Ti*k*Z to do the right thing. In any case, if we want a smooth, continuous curve, we might want to draw each component in one stroke. This can be achieved by choosing a different parametrization such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,thick,samples=101]
 ({(1/sqrt(2))+abs(\x)},{sign(\x)*sqrt(2*\x*\x+2*sqrt(2)*abs(\x))});
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,thick,samples=101]
 ({-(1/sqrt(2))-abs(\x)},{sign(\x)*sqrt(2*\x*\x+2*sqrt(2)*abs(\x))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps even simpler reparametrization is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=-4:4,smooth,thick,samples=101]
 ({sqrt(1/2+\x*\x/2)},\x);
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=-4:4,smooth,thick,samples=101]
 ({-sqrt(1/2+\x*\x/2)},\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be used

```
\documentclass{standalone} % or whatever
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=2,
    samples=101,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    axis lines=middle,
    ]
    \begin{scope}[
      domain=-2:-1/sqrt(2),
      ]
      \addplot[smooth] {sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)};
      \addplot[smooth] {-sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[
      domain=1/sqrt(2):2,
      ]
      \addplot[smooth] {sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)};
      \addplot[smooth] {-sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)};
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that we can actually just do

```
\addplot [domain=-2:2] {sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)};
```

for the upper part. It will just automatically. But then we get the hole. I'm assuming there is an option somewhere, where we can tell it to plot over `-2:2` and additionally evaluate at `+- 1/sqrt(2)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just to draw a connecting line over the gap.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=2:(1/sqrt(2)),smooth,thick,samples=100] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)}) --
  plot[domain=(1/sqrt(2)):2,smooth,thick,samples=100] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)});

\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain=-2:(-1/sqrt(2)),smooth,thick,samples=100] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)}) --
  plot[domain=(-1/sqrt(2)):-2,smooth,thick,samples=100] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x*\x)-1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]